# Deploy a stand-alone python script on PaaS service

Tags: python, google-app-engine, heroku, service, paas

I have Python script that is supposed to run once every few days to annotate some data on a remote database.

Which PaaS services (GAE, Heroku, etc.) allows for a stand-alone Python script to be deployed and executed via some sort of cron scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

GAE has a module called [cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron) and Heroku has [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler). Both are fairly easy to use and configure. You can check the documentation of both. As I do not have any other information on what you want to do I don’t know if one would be more suitable to you than the other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The script generates annotations for images via ML classification and to then annotate an entry in a MongoDB instance accordingly. Do you know whether any of the two solutions you suggested would be particularly cheaper than the other?

Comment: Well Heroku offers you MongoDB on their mLab module with is a DB-as-a-service while Google lets you deploy MongoDB on their Compute Engine module which is an IaaS. It’s difficult for me to know which would be cheaper without going into too much details but it seems to me that Heroku should be cheaper. It might also be easier to configure since with Google you’d have to set up a Compute Engine for the DB and an App Engine project to run your cron jobs. Hope that help!

Comment: You could potentially do this for free on PythonAnywhere if the ML script doesn't take up a lot of resources.